# Is the a way to plot that the distance between 2 moving averages has reached a specific percentage or tick value? Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I am attempting to calculate that the distance between the Ema50 and Ema100, and Ema100 and Ema150 are 12 points apart from each other respectively. Just trying to trigger a simple alert that a trend is starting. For both upward and downward trends.

Here is my attempt...

Trendcatcher = ema50 - ema100 >= 12 * syminfo.mintick and ema100 - ema150 >= 12 * syminfo.mintick or ema150 - ema100 >= 12 * syminfo.mintick and ema100 - ema50 >= 12 * syminfo.mintick

It works... but it only works when candles are crossing though the moving averages?
However the candles are not the reason for the alert... It's the distance between the Ema's that I need to trigger the alert.

How can I achieve this alert based on the distance of the moving averages on their own and not because a candle is moving though the averages?

Is this even possible in Pinescript?

Any help would be greatly apricated!
Big thanks in advance!

Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely possible!

Here is a version based on percentage:

```js
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © lysergik

//@version=5
indicator("stack trendcatcher question", format=format.percent)

// set percentage difference between
threshold_percentage = input.float(0.1, "threshold_percentage", minval=0.1)

// calculate emas
ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)
ema100 = ta.ema(close, 100)
ema150 = ta.ema(close, 150)

// calculate percentage difference between ma's at each candle close
diff1 = (ema50-ema100)/close*100
diff2 = (ema100-ema150)/close*100

// logic

bool up = diff1 >= threshold_percentage and diff2 >= threshold_percentage
bool down = diff1 <= threshold_percentage*-1 and diff2 <= threshold_percentage*-1

bool newUp = up[1] == false and up == true
bool newDown = down[1] == false and down == true

// front-end

hline(0)
plot(diff1, color=color.aqua)
plot(diff2, color=color.white)

plotshape(up ? 0 : na, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.lime, location=location.absolute)
plotshape(down ? 0 : na, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, location=location.absolute)

plotshape(newUp ? 0 : na, style=shape.diamond, size=size.small, color=color.lime, location=location.absolute)
plotshape(newDown ? 0 : na, style=shape.diamond, size=size.small, color=color.red, location=location.absolute)
```

[image: example]

I've plotted everything from the script into the indicator's front-end to exemplify its inner workings and help make it clear what it's doing.

The white and aqua lines are the percentage differences between ema100, ema 150 and ema 50, ema 100 respectively.

The tiny circles are plotted at every candle close are where the differences are both above or below the set threshold.

The small diamonds are plotted at the beginning of a new period of time where both differences are above or below the threshold. These boolean values can be used as the triggers for your alert!

I think you already know what to do to modify this script for use with number of ticks instead of percentage, but comment on this answer if you need any help doing so and I will be glad to help!

Comment: So how would I to modify this script for use with number of ticks instead of percentage? Big thanks!